# Printing an image to the bottom of each page using TCPDF?

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf

is there a way to print an image to the bottom of each page? Some sort of footer alternative so to say. My image code looks like that right now:

```
'<p><img src="' . $footerImage . '" /></p>';
```

Is that possible? If not, is it possible to print an image to the tcpdf footer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your using Php you'd echo out $footerImage and have a separate php included file with $footerImage pointed to the absolute footer image location. So for example:

home.php:

```
<?php include('vd.php'); ?>
<p><img src="<?php echo $footerImage; ?>" /></p>
```

vd.php:

```
<?php $footerImage = 'app/view/img1.html'; ?>
```

Is this of any help?